question on applications of the Skolem Noether Theorem from Benson Farb
D is a division algebra containing a finite field k in its center. If every element of D is algebraic over k then D is a field.
As per the hint if the center $K$ is not entire $D$ let $x\in D-K$. Then choose the polynomial of the minimal degree over $k$ that $x$ satisfies. I take the homomorphism $k[x]\to k[x]$ that takes $x\mapsto y$ for some other root of that minimal polynomial. So that we have $yxy^{-1}\neq x$ where such $y$ exists due to the Skolem Noether theorem. Now the hint asks to look $k[x,y]$. I am unable to proceed from here.
Any hint is welcome.
I feel like I have to use the fact that $k$ is a finite field somehow.
